# Getting data from a private constructor class in to main activity (Android in app purchases)

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to implement in app purchases with the billing library and I just have one thing that I am failing to implement for a few days now.

To begin with, my billing class is defined as so:

```
class BillingHelper private constructor(
    context: Context,
    private val defaultScope: CoroutineScope,
    knownInAppSKUs: Array<String>?
) {
```

For now, I am simply trying to obtain a single in app purchase details, which I have done successfully, but I can't manage to get it in to my main activity. The method that I use (after connecting to google play billing services) to query for the product details is as follows:

```
    private fun queryProducts() {
        val productList =
        listOf(
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                .setProductId("remove_ads")
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                .build()
        )

        val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(productList)

        billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params.build()) {
                billingResult,
                productDetailsList ->
            // Process the result
        }
    }
```

I would like to get the data in the async query to main activity. I am aware the implementation is most likely to be done with mutable state or shared flows, but I am fairly new to Kotlin so I failed to implement them. Specifically I failed to successfully collect them in the main activity. Could I perhaps turn this class in to a ViewModel and use LiveData?

Any tips or pointers on how to go about with implementing this are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Implemented my class as so:

```
class BillingHelper private constructor() : ViewModel() {
```

Used the following live data:

```
private val productData = MutableLiveData<ProductDetails>()
```

Sent the values back to main:

```
productData.postValue(productDetailsList[0])
...
fun getLiveData(): MutableLiveData<ProductDetails> {
    return productData
}
```

And finally obtain the values back in the main activity in the onCreate method as such:

```
val liveDataObserver: Observer<ProductDetails?> = Observer<ProductDetails?> {
    Log.i("billing", it.name)
}
bill.getLiveData().observe(this, liveDataObserver)
```

Also I removed context from constructors and instead now am getting context from application. Hope this is useful for someone!